# Is it acceptable (good practice?) to use I18n within config files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-i18n

So I was setting up my `config.mailer_sender` in the initializers/devise.rb file.

The client doesn't yet know what their 'from' address is going to be, so I figured I'd add it as a locale in case I also need it in other areas of the site. However, it wasn't working.

After a lot of searching I found a fix which suggested placing the following in application.rb:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

There is very little out there about using internationalisation in config files and so I'm now curious to know if there is a reason for that, i.e. it's not recommended!

Is there a better solution, or should config files be more detailed/explicit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 4.2 you can actually create config files for different settings:

```
# config/global.yml

development:
  email: "user@example.com"
```

And then in your app:

```
Rails.application.config_for(:global)["email"]
```

You can find more info here:

http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/08/25/the-lesser-known-features-in-rails-4-dot-2/

Comment: Thanks @yury, just what I was looking for. Love Justin's articles. I should have thought to search there before resorting to SO!!

Comment: Glad to help! His articles are great, and i'm also very surprised that this feature is not mentioned in the official Rails docs.